# Pytorch: merging two models (nn.Module)

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a model that's quite complicated and I therefore can't just call `self.fc.weight` etc. so I want to iterate over the model in some way.

The goal is to merge models this way: `m = alpha * n + (1 - alpha) * o` where `m` `n` and `o` are instances of the same class but trained differently. So for each parameter in these models, I want to assign initial values to `m` based on `n` and `o` as described in the equation and then continue the training procedure with `m` only.

I tried:

```
for p1, p2, p3 in zip(m.parameters(), n.parameters(), o.parameters()):
    p1 = alpha * p2 + (1 - alpha) * p3
```

But this does not assign new values *within* `m`.

```
for p1, p2, p3 in zip(m.parameters(), n.parameters(), o.parameters()):
    p1.fill_(alpha * p2 + (1 - alpha) * p3)
```

But this throws

> RuntimeError: a leaf Variable that requires grad has been used in an in-place operation.

And so I resorted to a working

```
m.load_state_dict({
    k: alpha * v1 + (1 - alpha) * v2 
    for (k, v1), (_, v2) in zip(n.state_dict().items(), o.state_dict().items())
})
```

Is there a better way to do this in Pytorch? Is it possible that I get gradient errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you need to get out from under PyTorch's autograd mechanics, which you can by simply doing

```
p1.data = alpha * p2.data+ (1 - alpha) * p3.data
```

The parameter's data is not in the parameter itself, but in the `data` member.

Comment: And so by doing this I'm enforcing the data is passed not the references so updates to p2 and/or p3 won't affect p1 and vice versa?

Comment: @ted Yes, you are performing an operation on "raw" tensors, like you would on an array in numpy for example.